# FileNotFoundException on call to Resources

Tags: c#, resources, filenotfoundexception

I have seen others ask this question but with no answers that have helped me. I have some code that I've used to assign an image to a node in a tree control. This has been working for some time now. However, recently I have been getting "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file '*ProjectName*.resources'.'"

```
     RadTreeNode node = new RadTreeNode( string.Format( "{0} ({1})", type, total ) );
     node.Image = Resources.Neutral; ///Error is here
```

It's not saying that it cannot find the file, it seems to be saying that it cannot find .resources. This seemed to be working up until now as an embedded file. The images are coming from a folder within the solution.

[image]

I should add that I had to remove the icon that I was using from the same folder because it could not be found on startup and prevented the program from starting, throwing the same error.

Could it be a recent attempt to move my app from .NET 4.6.1 to 4.7?

Comment: can you show how are you specifying the location of file ?

Comment: I add resources by double clicking Resources.resx and using the Add Resource>Add Existing File...